# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm getting this error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT H.Plotingan as 'Plotingan',
              E.EmployeeName as 'Nama',
              E.EmployeePosition as 'Jabatan',
              E.EmployeeNo as 'NIK',
              D.Tanggal,D.DutyCode
        FROM CobaDutyDetail D
        JOIN CobaDutyHeader H
          ON D.CobaDutyHeaderID = H.IDHeaderDuty
        JOIN Employee E
          ON H.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
       WHERE E.WorkLocation = 'JAKARTA'
       ORDER BY D.CreatedOn DESC)AS SOURCETABLE
       PIVOT(MAX(DutyCode)FOR TANGGAL IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30]))AS PIVOTTABLE
```

Comment: You have an order by in a derived table...

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Why do you need this `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: Have you tried removing `ORDER BY D.CreatedOn DESC`?

Comment: simple you should not Use Order by. If you Use Order by You Have to Select TOP Keyword

Comment: As the error states you could preserve the order by using TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML, i.e. select top (100) percent * from table1

Comment: @jimmy8ball Using `select top 100 percent` is not solving the problem, it's working around the error message. In hebrew we say "להכשיר את השרץ" - meaning to approve something as "kosher" even if it's not. The problem is not the error message, the problem is that the `order by` clause is meaningless and should not be there in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relational model specifies that the tuples of a relation have no specific order. In other words, rows in a database table have no specific order.
Therefor, when you are creating anything that can be references as a table (i.e views, derived tables etc') you can't specify an `order by` clause unless it's needed for restricting the results (with the use of `top` or `offset`).
You can use the `order by` clause with the `for xml` clause, since creating an xml is not the same as creating a table.

Now that I've explained the reason behind the error message you get, here is the solution - Simply remove the `order by` clause from your derived table:

```
SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT H.Plotingan as 'Plotingan',
              E.EmployeeName as 'Nama',
              E.EmployeePosition as 'Jabatan',
              E.EmployeeNo as 'NIK',
              D.Tanggal,D.DutyCode
        FROM CobaDutyDetail D
        JOIN CobaDutyHeader H
          ON D.CobaDutyHeaderID = H.IDHeaderDuty
        JOIN Employee E
          ON H.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
       WHERE E.WorkLocation = 'JAKARTA'
       ) AS SOURCETABLE
       PIVOT(MAX(DutyCode)FOR TANGGAL IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])) AS PIVOTTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not reasonable to bloat a subquery with a order by because the more external query ill "see" just the result dataset and ill use it the same way independent of the dataset order. If you want that `ORDER BY` baddly you can fill a temp table or table variable and use it instead.

```
SELECT H.Plotingan as [Plotingan],
              E.EmployeeName as [Nama],
              E.EmployeePosition as [Jabatan],
              E.EmployeeNo as [NIK],
              D.Tanggal,D.DutyCode
into #temp
        FROM CobaDutyDetail D
        JOIN CobaDutyHeader H
          ON D.CobaDutyHeaderID = H.IDHeaderDuty
        JOIN Employee E
          ON H.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
       WHERE E.WorkLocation = 'JAKARTA'
       ORDER BY D.CreatedOn DESC)AS SOURCETABLE

SELECT * FROM #temp AS SOURCETABLE
       PIVOT(MAX(DutyCode)FOR TANGGAL IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])) AS PIVOTTABLE
```

But that's not advisable. The correct answer as Zohar pointed out is ti get rid of that ordering clause.